# How to reset GNOME default theme?

Tags: gnome, themes

I wonder and I needed it sometimes. Some time we install many themes and it gets worst.

Comment: Hey, is this still a problem for you, or did you get it fixed. If it's fixed, then you should accept one of the answers below to draw a line under this question.

Answer (score 7):

DO NOT

> rm -rf ~/.*

You will delete your configurations for every application in your profile, not just the gnome theme settings.

Instead, do:

> rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd
>   .metacity

Answer (score 6):

If by default theme, you mean the one that came preinstalled with 10.04 and 10.10, that's called Ambiance, and it can be found in **System** -> **Preferences** -> **Appearance**. The installed themes will be listed here in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean the theme that comes with a default install of Ubuntu, go to System->Preferences->Appearance and click on **Ambiance** (dark theme) or **Radiance** (light theme).

If you instead want the non-Ubuntu-default theme that GNOME ships by default, click on **Clearlooks**.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following commands to change the theme. Ambiance is the default theme as people have mentioned above

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "Ambiance"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Ambiance"
```

Comment: What is the equivalent for Ubuntu 22.10?