# Gnome calculator broken, white screen

Tags: 20.04, gnome, plasma, gnome-calculator

I recently installed KDE Plasma to test it out, but I didn't like it so I booted back to GNOME only to see that everything is broken, the top-bar, icons, everything. In order to reset everything, I uninstalled Plasma and reset GNOME with the command
`dconf reset -f /org/gnome` and rebooted, but now when I open `gnome-calculator`, I see this:

[image: Gnome calculator screenshot]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Edit:
The current theme is Orchis-Dark which I've set from GNOME tweaks. If I were to change the theme back to adwaita, it blends in okay:
[image: GNOME calculator with adwaita]

But even if I switch it to adwaita-dark, it breaks again:
[image: GNOME calculator with adwaita-dark]

Edit 2:
I've noticed the same problem with System Monitor:
[image]

Comment: 1. Try changing themes back to the defaults. 2. When you run `gnome-calculator` in a terminal, does it show any error messages?

Comment: you might need to re-install ubuntu for everything to be as it was

Comment: First temporarily create a new account, see if the issue happens there also (I do not expect). This way, you can see whether the problem is with the user configuration or with the system.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I ran it from the terminal, but there aren't any error messages.

Comment: Hi @vanadium I tried setting the theme to Orchis-Dark in a new account and it worked fine, just doesn't work for this account.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried changing the theme back to adwaita and back to orchis dark but the issue remains

Comment: This way, you know reinstalling will not help. You have to look for the problem in your current user account. You did not mention whether the issue is there with a default theme such as Adwaita or Yaru. Add all this information usefull to debug the problem to your question.

Comment: @vanadium I think the issue is that this white area doesn't turn black, ive seen that even in adwaita-dark or yaru-dark it remains white, so where could that issue be from?

Comment: @Vthechamp  From the tests you did above, I suspect either an environment variable or an override settings file for GTK theme that stored  in user home folder probably. KDE has a tool that create those to make GTK & QT look similar in KDE .  The tool is called `kde-gtk-config`, possible solution is either use it to set a theme compatible for both or look for the exact files in your user home folder. I did't have time  to recheck yet as I'm still not yes familiar with the GTK4.

Comment: try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt install -f`

Answer (score 0):

I have read many posts about switching desktops and the experts often answer that the only way to fix it is to re-install your OS. I know that you don't want to hear that so here is a solutions that has worked for me.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`

If that doesn't fix your GUI problem then type
`env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`
and report back to us with the result (if will show the current desktop/s installed)

Comment: `$ env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` just returns `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME` and the command above does nothing, just asks me to select my display manager which i set to `gdm3`

Comment: My bad, try `ls /usr/bin/*session` to confirm how many desktops are actually installed. It seems they sahre a lot of files and switching desktops can leave icons and other GUI functions pathed incorrectly. The answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1378762/kde-plasma-5-missing-icons-after-using-gnome-desktop-environment relating to removing tmp files is worth a go as it does not reconfigure anything and I feel it is safe to try.

Comment: This is the output:/usr/bin/dbus-run-session*              /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session*
/usr/bin/gnome-session*                 /usr/bin/plasma_session*
/usr/bin/gnome-session-custom-session*

Comment: Hmm, I tried switching some themes on my 20.10 and was able to get everything back to basic using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` alternatively you could try some answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/5739/how-to-reset-gnome-default-theme

Comment: can upgrading to 22.04 fix the problem?